# Add comments on left side in Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, comments

I'm a student trying to create a Word template displaying comments on the left side of the page on even page number and on the right side on odd page number. I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the **Layout** tab, click the dialog box launcher in the lower-right corner of the **Page Setup** group. In the **Page Setup** dialog box, under **Pages**, in the **Multiple pages** field, select **Mirror margins**. Under **Margins**, you'll then probably also want to increase the **Outside** value, to give your comments more room.

In the **Styles** gallery on the **Home** tab, or in the **Styles** pane if you have that open, right-click whatever style you're using for your comments, and then click **Modify**. In the **Modify Style** dialog box, on the **Format** drop-down menu in the lower-left corner, click **Frame**. Under **Text wrapping**, **Around** should be selected automatically. Under **Size**, set the width that you want your comments to have within the outside margin that you set earlier. Under **Horizontal**, set the **Position** field to **Outside**, and the **Relative** field to **Page**. You'll probably also want to set a **Distance from text** value, so that your body text doesn't get too close to your comment text.

That's it. Here's an example.

[image]

Comment: But can we do this with the built-in comment function in Word.  I didn't have access to the frame tab while my comment style was selected.

Comment: Oh, you meant Word's comment 'bubbles'? Sorry, I misunderstood. No, those always appear on the right, as far as I know. Because they aren't per se part of the page, they aren't affected by page layout settings such as mirrored margins, and a lot of settings that can be applied to other styles can't be applied to them – or else they can be applied but have no particular visible effect.